# VSE: how to duplicate an existing mask?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

So I'm in a scenario where I made a mask, but I need another version of the same mask only inverted. Basic question: How do I duplicate the existing mask so I have different mask profiles of the same thing (from there I can set one as inverted easy enough)?

Its easy enough to make a 2nd mask, and then copy and pasting the old mask into it and inverting then saving. But that's assuming its a static mask with no keyframes/movement. Say I have a ton of keyframes, then I'd have to go back and forth and copy and paste the different movements and insert keyframes etc....really really time consuming, its redoing the entire original mask almost. I tried using dope sheet (mask) but when I copy and paste the original and its keyframes it always says you cant do that for masks or something.

Assuming there is no feature of this kind available: Is there a way to take the strip the mask is applied to and invert the mask just for the one strip it resides on? Like I need an inverted version to apply to a single strip, but I need the not inverted version applied to many other strips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the image editor you can click the little number button (probably says "2" on it) next to the mask to create a copy.

[image: mask]

Answer (score 1):

That's gone now, it only makes a new mask, but for anyone looking for this answer, I'm using 3.2 and you have to find it in the Outliner, display mode "Blender file" under masks, then right-click copy and right-click paste to make a duplicate Mask.The new copy will be available now in the dropdown in the Masks editor.